# Django doesn't keep connections alive, even though CONN_MAX_AGE is set to non-zero

Tags: django, postgresql, gunicorn, django-database

I am using Django 4.2 + PostgreSQL 15 and it has 4 Gunicorn workers.

```
CONN_MAX_AGE = 60
CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS = True
```

So, from what I understand, if I run a request that uses the database, Django will keep the connection alive somehow.

But that doesn't seem to happen:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY backend_start DESC;
```

Doesn't show any open connections. None at all. Only `logical, replication launcher, autovacuum launcher, walwriter, background writer, checkpointer` which are not created by Django.

How do I keep connections alive? I've thoroughly read the documentation and every related thread on SO.

Another thing that I don't understand is, even if my connections were kept alive (which they are not), what process would keep connections alive? Is it WSGI loop?

Comment: You normally configure this in the `settings.py` more specifically in the `DATABASES` variable.

Comment: That was it, I spent way too much time. Thank you!